# SQL Profiler connection details

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2000, sql-server-profiler

When you startup a standard trace the first settings you see will be the current database connections.

In my case there is about 10 entries, all of whome are the same username, however some are dateformat dmy and some are mdy. The asp website seems to pick a connection from the pool and uses it,  it appears to pick one of 3 and all are set to dmy however every connection should be mdy.  Since they are all the same username and that user is set to us_english where else might the connection be getting the dateformat entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- The application is issuing SET DATEFORMAT
- The app is using a DSN with/without translation

By default, the connection default is defined by SQL Server default settings.

Comment: Turns out to be the answer.  Although it is actually another app that is setting the connection dateformat,  it is being returned to the pool and retains it's settings and our application sometimes ipcks up one of these connections.